# Source culture for clipboard-copied Excel data

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to paste copied Excel data in my software.

After inspecting clipboard content with [ClipView](http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/index.html), I need to read somewhere the culture of the source workbook, to determine which are the **Decimal separator** and the **Thousand separator**.

I find that the **HTML Format** part of the clipboard contains that informations in the style tag:

```
<style>
<!--
    table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
    ....
-->
</style>
```

Unfortunately, when you copy through Terminal Server / Citrix, this information is gone since the **HTML Format** part is stripped out by the RDP protocol, so I can't rely on it.

So, I'm trying to find out if the **Biff5** / **Biff8** / **Biff 12** parts contains that information.

I searched the web for .net Biff readers but it doesn't seem that they expose what I need.

Any one has ideas?

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but is it not possible to let the user select/specify the culture instead of you guessing it - assuming user's culture and workbook culture are two separate things? If user culture and workbook culture are the same, you can use something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @greatbear302 Yes, it's possible, but it's exactly the way I would try to avoid. Said that, user culture and workbook culture are likely to be different since the software is used via RDP/Citrix.

Comment: found this SO link similar to your post. it uses Excel interop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914643/determine-excel-version-culture-via-microsoft-office-interop-excel, and also this MSDN article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914643/determine-excel-version-culture-via-microsoft-office-interop-excel

Comment: sorry, wrong link for MSDN. this is correct one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @greatbear302 If i'm not wrong, the articles talk about determining the current culture of the current Excel installation, which is not what I want. I need to understand if some Excel binary formats (Biff) contains that culture information for a saved workbook or clipboard-copied data.

Comment: i haven't tried it, but it seems it instantiates a thread of installed excel and then you add your spreadsheet to the thread. once this is done, you retrieve the thread's culture. thread's culture and spreadsheet culture are the same at that point.

Comment: @greatbear302 I currently work with SpreadsheetGear (a third-party component for Excel viewing and modification), but when you open a file or a stream, you need to supply the culture. So I deduce that this is an info of the viewer, not something present in the workbook, so what I'm looking for, ***simply doesn't exist***.

Comment: @greatbear302 By the way, SpreadsheetGear is unable to open a Biff from memorystream, so I think it's little different from standard OOXML.